# Joining multiple tables with filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I got multiple tables and i'm only using 3 for testing. I don't know if this is the right approach.

AccntTbl

```
  id    accnt   amount    date
---------------------------------
  1      xxx     10.00   1/1/2016
  2      yyy     20.00   1/1/2016
  3      zzz     30.00   1/1/2016
```

SupplyTbl

```
  id   accnt    supply   date
-------------------------------
  1     xxx     5.00     1/10/2016
  1     xxx     5.00     2/14/2016
```

IssuedTbl

```
  id   accnt    issued  date
---------------------------------
  1     xxx      3.00   1/9/2016
  1     xxx      2.00   2/1/2016
```

and the result will be like this if filter to JANUARY

```
    id    accnt    amount   issued   balance   
   --------------------------------------------
    1     xxx      15.00     3.00     12.00    
    2     yyy      20.00     0.00     20.00    
    3     zzz      30.00     0.00     30.00
```

and if FEBRUARY

```
   id    accnt    amount    issued   balance    
  ---------------------------------------------
    1     xxx      20.00     5.00    15.00      
    2     yyy      20.00     0.00     0.00      
    3     zzz      30.00     0.00     0.00
```

and here's my query that i've come up with

```
SELECT accnttbl.id, 
       accnttbl.accnt, 
       Sum(accnttbl.amount) 
       + Sum(SupplyTbl.supply) AS amount, 
       issuedtbl.issued 
FROM   accnttbl 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, 
                         Sum(supply) AS supply, 
                         date 
                  FROM   supplytbl 
                  GROUP  BY id, 
                            date) AS SupplyTbl 
              ON accnttbl.id = SupplyTbl.id 
                 AND Month(SupplyTbl.date) BETWEEN 1 AND 2 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT id. Sum(issued) AS issued, 
                         date 
                  FROM   issuedtbl 
                  GROUP  BY id, 
                            date) 
              ON accnttbl.id = issuedtbl.id 
                 AND Month(issuedtbl.date) BETWEEN 1 AND 2 
WHERE  Year(accnttbl.date) = 2016 
GROUP  BY accnttbl.id, 
          accnttbl.accnt
```

and i kinda mess up..glad for any help :)

the result be like this..in JANUARY

```
id    accnt   amount   issued
```

---

```
1      xxx     30.00      10.00 
2      yyy     20.00       0.00
```

and in FEBRUARY

```
1      xxx     60.00      20.00
2      yyy     20.00       0.00
```

with the value that i been given..it just..it doubled the amount on its own..the result are wrong..why is that ?

Comment: Are you getting any error / output ? What is the result you are getting ?

Comment: i didn't get the result that i've expected..

Comment: What is the result you are getting , please post that also .

Comment: Also , what database are you using ?

Comment: im using SQL 2012 sir..

Comment: To get 0 for `issued` and `balance` , you must use `COALESCE(SUM(supply), 0)` and `COALESCE(SUM(balance), 0)` inside the subquery .

Comment: Your subqueries do not have aliases, so this query cannot run in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
SELECT AccntTbl.id, AccntTbl.accnt
    , SUM(AccntTbl.amount) + SUM(SupplyTbl.supply) as amount
    , SUM(IssuedTbl.issued) as issued
    , (SUM(amount) - SUM(issued)) as balance
    FROM   AccntTbl LEFT JOIN 
           (SELECT id, COALESCE(SUM(supply), 0) AS supply, date FROM SupplyTbl 
                  GROUP By id, date) AS SupplyTbl
    ON     AccntTbl.id = SupplyTbl.id AND (MONTH(SupplyTbl.date) BETWEEN 
                                           1 AND 2) 
                    LEFT JOIN 
           (SELECT id, COALESCE(SUM(issued),0) as issued, date from IssuedTbl
                  GROUP By id, date )
    ON     AccntTbl.id = IssuedTbl.id AND (MONTH(IssuedTbl.date) BETWEEN 
                                           1 AND 2)    
    WHERE (YEAR(AccntTbl.date) = 2016)
    GROUP By AccntTbl.id, AccntTbl.accnt
    ;
```

In sql anything added with `NULL` is `NULL` . So in your subquery if you are not using `COALESCE`, you are adding your value with `NULL`, hence you are not getting your desired result.

Comment: the thing is i think i got a problem with this lines
`(SELECT id, COALESCE(SUM(supply), 0) AS supply, date FROM SupplyTbl 
 GROUP By id, date) AS SupplyTbl
 ON     AccntTbl.id = SupplyTbl.id AND (MONTH(SupplyTbl.date) BETWEEN 1 AND 2) 
 LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT id, COALESCE(SUM(issued),0) as issued, date from IssuedTbl
                  GROUP By id, date )
 ON     AccntTbl.id = IssuedTbl.id AND (MONTH(IssuedTbl.date) BETWEEN 1 AND 2)`

Comment: You are still not getting results ? Can you post in sqlfiddle ?